# Symfony project using CURL - building project with API

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1

I have never used a PHP framework before and am considering using Symfony for my next one.  However, I have already built an API which has all my main classes.  I will therefore connect to this API using CURL.   Can anyone advise on where to start with such a project.  I am working through a Symfony tutorial but none of it seems to apply to what I need to do as I do not need to create database connections or classes as I will be building this project on my existing API.

Comment: What are your "main classes" -- Symfony2 has a very distinctive way of what classes you need to build and what goes into other configuration files. My best guess is that you may not even be needing your own classes.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I had explained properly and so have edited the above.  I built an API and so need to build a project within Symfony to allow me to cnnect with the API and use my classes that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a lot of what you see in the Symfony tutorials you might be able to get away with Silex. Silex is a mini-framework with alot of the core aspects of Symfony, but without the extra stuff.

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: Thanks but I have decided to go ahead and use Symfony.  I need a basic tutorial so Iknow how to start a simple project without databases and classes which uses REST.

Comment: For REST you could look into the FOSRestBundle. This bundle simplifies uses REST with Symfony significantly. As for tutorials, there aren't many out there, but basically what you would be doing is building your project mostly in and around custom controllers (that aren't attached to a database entry)